# Analysis of $\mathbb C^{n\times n} \to \mathbb C^{n\times n}$ functions and integrals of them.

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, complex-analysis, soft-question, analyticity

Due to a previous question being [too sloppily written by me](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2844758/complex-analysis-for-matrix-functions/2844862#2844862) I here try to be a bit more clear on what I wondered.

For functions defined
$$\mathbb C^{n\times n} \to \mathbb C^{n\times n} : A+Bi \to f(A+Bi)$$
for example by power series expansion:
$$f(A+Bi) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty C_k(A+Bi)^k$$
Can we derive results similar to those in analysis of one complex variable? Or more specifically for what kind of definition of analyticity and integral would it even make sense ?

Comment: You can develop a theory of holomorphic functions in all complex Banach spaces, such as the space of matrices. I am no specialist, but I think it has lots of analogies with the standard theory of holomorphic functions.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro It sounds interesting, but I probably need to study more in depth. Do you know any book?

Comment: Well, on second thought, that was not great advice. You don't use the Banach space structure of the space of matrices; what you use is that matrices are linear operators on a complex Banach space. Please forget about my comment and follow cactus's advice instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [holomorphic functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus). You can start from the content of that link, or books on Functional Analysis like Yosida's "Functional Analysis", Dunford and Schwartz "Linear operators". Or more basis ones like Conway's Functional Analysis should have a little of it.